# Laravel 8.x PDF file validation is not working correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation, laravel-filesystem

I am working on Laravel 8.x. My task is to validate .PDF file on server side. Everyting working fine but when I upload a valid PDF file it is not validating and returning with an error.
My source code is following. Please correct my mistakes if you find

Thanks

> blade file

```
<form class="w-100" id="addnotes" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('upload-member-reports') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" name="report-file" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Upload Reports</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <label class="file ">
        <input type="file" name="reportfile" id="reportfile"  aria-label="File browser example">
        <span class="file-custom"></span>
    </label>
    @if($errors->has('reportfile'))
        <div class="error text-danger">{{ $errors->first('reportfile') }}</div>
    @endif
    <input type="date" name="reportdate" class="form-control mt-20px" value="{{ old('reportdate') }}" placeholder="Select Date">
    <!-- <textarea type="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Notes..."></textarea> -->
    @if($errors->has('reportdate'))
        <div class="error text-danger mt-5px">{{ $errors->first('reportdate') }}</div>
    @endif
    <input type="hidden" name="manager_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="{{ $id }}">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

> controller file

```
public function uploadMemberReports( Request $request ){
    # Validation  Rules
    $rules = [
        'reportdate'=>'required',
        'reportfile' => 'required|mimes:pdf',
    ];
    $messages = [
        'reportdate.required' =>'Date is required.',
        'reportfile.required' => 'File is required.',
        'reportfile.mimes' => 'Only PDF files are allowed.',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        # if validations fails redirect back with errors
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {
        # next action
    }
}
```

When I try with valid PDF file it returning with error like following

> The reportfile failed to upload.

Edit:
The request array response

```
Array
(
    [_token] => yaX0ohRjl6tR298Zd9WeSLcgxcoVQ9nPx3K5gO4S
    [reportdate] => 2021-01-12
    [manager_id] => 2
    [member_id] => 4
    [reportfile] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => labreports_12.pdf
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/octet-stream
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1
            [hashName:protected] => 
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Try with `'reportfile' => 'required|mimes:application/pdf',`

Comment: @sta tried already, but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have several causes. But Frontend looks good at first glance. It could be a server problem. For example FileSize, MimeType. You can output the request variable in the first step to rule out the possibility that the PDF has not arrived.

Edit (see at your comments): 'required|mimes:application/pdf'

Comment: already tried with - 'required|mimes:application/pdf'. still gettig same issue

Comment: see the array response of $request. I updated the question

Comment: Thanks! What i see is that  [hashName:protected] and            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private]  has no values. Maybe increase your filesize on server. or try with an small pdf file.

Comment: It's working with the low size PDF file. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Simply add "enctype" into your form**

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your_action">
```

**Basic Usage Of MIME Rule**

```
'reportfile' => 'mimes:png'
```

**Just try with full extensions**

```
'reportfile' => 'mimes:application/pdf'
```

OR

```
"reportfile" => 'mimetypes:application/pdf'
```

Full listing of MIME types and extensions https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Comment: already tried with - 'required|mimes:application/pdf'. still gettig same issue

Comment: @RamChander I have the same problem using laravel 8.x in windows with laragon.. did you solved this problem?

Comment: I solved adding  enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form

Comment: @FreddyDaniel yes i have solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following above @maik Lowrey, I sucessfully used :

'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048'

works very well ! ! ! (Answered here cause i don't have lvl to comment his answer)